# How to stop a ui5 server using command line

Tags: sapui5

How will I stop a ui5 server that is started using "ui5 serve" using command line. Please note that i cannot stop using 'ctr+c'.

Comment: that depends on how and where you did start it.

Comment: Could you please specify a little more about your environment ? (OS, Node Version etc. )
Theses things can be important e.g. [https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/290](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/290)